# VBScript: Function returns an array

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I have some VBScript code where a function returns an array.

```
function PreProcessFile (sFile)

    dim deData(3)

    ''populate deData with strings

    PreProcessFile = deData

End function
```

The code calling this function errs with a type mismatch.  Any thoughts?

```
'' VBScript source code
Dim m_deData(3)
set m_deData = PreProcessFile("someFile.txt")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't explicitly dim the size of the array outside the function and don't use set:

```
'' VBScript source code
Dim m_deData
m_deData = PreProcessFile("someFile.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks... I thought I was done with VBScript years ago but it found its way back to me...

Comment: Powershell... arrghh nooo!! What were they thinking!!.  Python may be an alternative or even JScript but frankly Powershell is a disaster.  It goes way over the average administrators head and developers ought to have something better to do like writing software.