# How to return array from function using VBScript

Tags: arrays, excel, vbscript, vba

I have 10 records (rows) in my Excel sheet and I am taking it into array and I am not able to return it from function. I get only the last value. Below is my script.

```
Function fnFetchDataUsingArray()
    Dim arrExcelValues()
    sSheetName = Environment.Value("TestName")

    sExcelWorkbookPath = "I:\ProLinkIII_TestAutomation\trunk\ProLink_TestAutomation\Datasheet\DTSheet_5700C.xlsx"

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(sExcelWorkbookPath)

    objExcel.Visible = False
    Set currentWorkSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sSheetName)

    i = 1
    x = 0

    Do Until objExcel.Cells(i, 2).Value = ""
        ReDim Preserve arrExcelValues(x)

        arrExcelValues(x) = objExcel.Cells(i, 2).Value

        i = i + 1
        x = x + 1

        fnFetchDataUsingArray = arrExcelValues(x-1)
    Loop

    objExcel.Quit
End Function
```

Calling the function:

```
arr = fnFetchDataUsingArray()
MsgBox arr
```

I am getting only the last value. Attached screenshot of my datasheet.

[image: Datasheet Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript: Function returns an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654888/vbscript-function-returns-an-array)

Answer (score 2):

The line `fnFetchDataUsingArray = arrExcelValues(x-1)` is just repeatedly assigning the last value in `arrExcelValues` to the return value of the function.
You need to assign the array `arrExcelValues` to the return value of the function after your Do loop.

So after your loop try this: `fnFetchDataUsingArray = arrExcelValues`.